# Dynamic route returns favicon.ico instead of variable in Flask

Tags: python, flask, url, dynamic, flask-restful

Good afternoon,

I am currently developing a Flask application, and I am experiencing an error that had never happened to me before. I am currently setting up a dynamic route in Flask. This is the piece of code:

```
@app.route('/viewcar/<string:carId>')
def viewcar(carId):
    print(carId)
    car = Car.getCarById(carId)
    return render_template("car.html", car=car)
```

However, when I pass any variable to the URL (let's say "http://127.0.0.1:5000/viewcar/4975facbbce511b65e14f44719340029-cf161184-91fc"), when I check the output in the console, it says that carId equals to favicon.ico instead of "4975facbbce511b65e14f44719340029-cf161184-91fc". Any ideas on what could this be? It has never happened to me before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try like with curl or something else that uses pure http, not from a browser or other http client?

Comment: Did u ever solve this? running into the same issue while hosting on AWS

Comment: @bnicholl: Check out my answer. Pretty much some browsers request favicon.ico on their own and if it doesn't exist it can get caught up in your dynamic routing.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue today too, however I noticed that when I launch my development flask server at http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in Chrome (version 104.0.5112.101), the console logs show that it grabbed `favicon.ico` for the variable I was grabbing from the URL, but when I used Safari (version 15.3) the URL variable was correctly parsed.

Now I'm starting to think it's a browser related?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32609877)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  running into the same issue while hosting on AWS

Answer (score 0):

I'm really new to flask myself and also came across this issue. For me it was that I had another route in my module that got executed prior to this route I intended and the variable name was being assigned there so it seems the next (default?) argument must have been used in my intended route. I'm sure I'm only describing this halfway correct but hopefully it helps somebody debug their issue a little quicker.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32601264)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in the head tag of html file (`car.html` in this case)

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
```

The problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to cause an issue in chrome when ran locally, but not safari locally. Furthermore, when I attempted to deploy my app on AWS app runner, this issue persisted on both browsers. Adding the below line of code made it work locally and on AWS app runner

```
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
```

If anyone has insight into why this is happening in flask, I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

I Just ran into this issue today using dynamic routing in the Next.js app router. Turns out it is common for many browsers to request favicon.ico. I can think of three solutions, the first is the option I went with.

1. In Flask the static folder hosts your static files (public folder in my case); if you don't have one create it at project root. Then just create an empty favicon.ico file there and it will take precedence over your dynamic route.
2. Add a specific route in your application to handle favicon.ico.
3. Check for requests to favicon.ico in the dynamic route itself.